# lower triangular heat-map in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, correlation

I'm trying to plot a pearson correlation heat map in R on a certain dataset.

The rows and columns of the heat map shall be the same, thus I'm trying to plot a lower triangular plot for it.

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
cormat_UCS_pearson <- round(cor(t(UCS_pearson)),5)
```

Where

UCS_perason originally has 58387 columns and two rows, but due to constraints, I'll show

UCS_pearson[,c(1:500)]

```
structure(c(-0.160788424826038, -0.0257422401750742, -0.0518775542691747, 
-0.165841754235558, 0.0621416947620554, 0.222940671263803, 0.0182177186967158, 
-0.269665933111091, 0.0108734083848302, -0.0680795555145049, 
-0.0314603016241517, 0.100409630242065, 0.491174247937916, 0.153922391186737, 
0.0768587331222585, -0.143707163610835, 0.0312164212874025, 0.399184814292453, 
-0.153967984972866, 0.204591797534103, -0.0588748849845526, 0.0221869847261395, 
-0.12301177706225, 0.0826808454400297, -0.126961149111363, -0.174469497173807, 
0.256151155743578, 0.240852646359448, 0.10638094887544, -0.0815900402383247, 
0.250473442293516, -0.0238179204071666, -0.144651564807006, -0.280937576894735, 
-0.111684092128957, -0.0197076858668464, -0.193220376106192, 
-0.0426606909811688, -0.126004286407775, 0.0947536170087334, 
0.057738977299137, 0.103571460702936, -0.0157257710015432, 0.149407092075215, 
0.127302014752183, -0.206738230688861, -0.060775963589793, -0.189757106698901, 
-0.0371024550402435, 0.291246274232428, -0.194659994239295, -0.0689694149696159, 
0.160163113758826, 0.17502435406333, -0.341828765694863, 0.0885796257422236, 
0.13248737580755, -0.0851616477975954, -0.0225921176857983, -0.00496786994749575, 
-0.17139210128259, -0.0754857264355948, -0.326059268523373, -0.197034490794277, 
0.187118821445185, -0.3258318107255, -0.0147060076874178, 0.20744856580739, 
0.0259449619062298, 0.0133471912808717, -0.089235642663198, -0.104758508695755, 
-0.219995628159254, -0.163556018826001, 0.217837787973358, -0.0383668156955706, 
0.0446037028532433, 0.0546081091603452, 0.0198990872830052, -0.299886754594252, 
0.0690624544291303, -0.151075386942631, -0.0245980828870225, 
0.325134214974123, -0.178998579719923, -0.197501542084414, -0.125821792361664, 
-0.0831374400037483, -0.0543175598721145, -0.107434351704301, 
0.127833423926045, -0.243709143035783, 0.087296540658909, -0.303868722218803, 
0.0549884854381427, 0.00283222132557367, -0.360218483376441, 
-0.129891049916006, -0.0459448401386707, -0.144868402432394, 
-0.0535188683995115, -0.303725269328798, -0.0483750689864511, 
-0.207767080382625, 0.0559883421655016, 0.0858848566417679, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.116958996376998, 0.217790881211909, 0.0101501061185678, 
-0.202050192341405, -0.0881431858631242, -0.194286462214668, 
-0.19180463728637, -0.0217840096309176, 0.131094012852616, 0.145435974509276, 
0.382016642961684, 0.143664069160626, -0.0703444124193061, 0.270682340825076, 
-0.123773734884045, -0.174898297084319, -0.108567975049227, 0.387983258609705, 
0.015828181483406, 0.27251194494083, -0.167524773792288, -0.307520405026975, 
-0.338574553003239, 0.232510614134642, -0.304841647448181, -0.0877809113428862, 
0.0351379398344911, 0.354532976072275, -0.0103688020125061, 0.0670146594763316, 
0.431473799708244, 0.213550373925138, -0.254128008083358, 0.238998869027372, 
0.245751872540891, -0.201280379473751, 0.266977857736016, -0.0777428082918172, 
-0.0686789231261643, 0.190746571654957, 0.255804100930973, 0.188071238929165, 
-0.15567163862281, -0.0398148182192045, 0.0462693932429652, -0.00507416965589838, 
0.00363537787013793, -0.0188385425590899, 0.0275070608784838, 
-0.0534385432423223, -0.235533303097878, 0.000109987362191777, 
0.153735230223155, 0.209660579263017, 0.364093077082748, -0.200223246642941, 
-0.279468292091011, -0.327788622359998, -0.161785570342061, 0.0221858209145764, 
-0.089650270941241, 0.044839622245306, 0.0167494127674376, 0.17763975775981, 
-0.211907993676722, 0.476249412131041, -0.127568417870314, 0.111871434618033, 
0.0102134076903728, -0.165771097571374, -0.0262893880607643, 
-0.24267144356801, 0.0186639441848443, 0.0889160526448091, -0.0275168070171429, 
0.105462484914279, -0.104650618921904, 0.485111478944573, -0.0547230640788596, 
0.418102872004007, -0.057518923097887, -0.272661215158949, -0.117124831113974, 
0.103465628421468, 0.0130711099362795, 0.193421167301985, 0.185748166363864, 
0.116518045189166, -0.0535005003380154, 0.146576772396211, -0.0400786368245271, 
-0.355485812798769, 0.451651830648632, -0.366605461937997, 0.172424549663343, 
-0.140341757305126, 0.0767729688333064, -0.250163351333159, 0.164629010363882, 
0.0934583124974739, -0.0257982745866111, 0.143182112676179, -0.0038174243480748, 
-0.130737192889484, 0.314900386584229, 0.214116977066315, -0.00490172883881734, 
0.308646252172375, -0.373169880595436, 0.360984980326363, -0.00677448042462275, 
-0.277436852875204, 0.129349565175812, -0.325470301363098, -0.234973619509544, 
-0.164824854977916, -0.0292766889951448, -0.0907647963237643, 
-0.319864057611299, 0.0270188473125247, 0.0981459337969273, -0.103491183966377, 
0.20984231852361, 0.317321366699691, 0.498494858783593, -0.055812813462925, 
0.0811661656281664, -0.280852499373267, -0.171357384217252, -0.0282465534706698, 
-0.0387480765018486, -0.129146457915067, -0.470374989360243, 
-0.180601632505367, -0.142395528689498, -0.230812618979536, -0.328663331622077, 
0.667148931331779, -0.310787006809799, 0.607484764648746, -0.0695639978289592, 
0.571428846305687, 0.121589240587617, -0.149946440834327, -0.00049796651995692, 
-0.0273667377723118, -0.216744952108681, 0.0720981060950985, 
-0.0201231966695146, -0.121282535513109, -0.270602854434521, 
0.182350144023858, 0.103005527927574, 0.155195552830089, -0.144345670507073, 
-0.168741467053413, 0.148040310295331, 0.196092346617121, NA, 
NA, -0.159639365076587, 0.00770350895130156, -0.18495611211399, 
0.0666486303528997, -0.0766142699859562, -0.188493474455737, 
-0.0435048945218461, -0.223117732044948, -0.0238548540996054, 
-0.317445711246788, NA, NA, 0.101286619156465, 0.0950642157902226, 
-0.189292595533748, 0.473693004640604, 0.0997608933151469, 0.154916175788068, 
-0.0218696636548777, 0.305267207338952, 0.127162496463241, 0.290876940067172, 
0.147676819728199, 0.326243074259712, 0.235646247829676, -0.0417812081449229, 
0.0429954391404932, -0.291524447226673, -0.0526985369068797, 
0.605044141128949, -0.381892266884492, 0.0181871141905498, 0.334334514019781, 
0.281403732730617, 0.431864700200925, -0.198503801251651, 0.205059732297505, 
-0.131730304224948, -0.060453849529942, -0.0647619911734703, 
-0.166359804231634, 0.282486170805339, 0.0100090947328073, -0.37346431271674, 
0.421939167218388, -0.504999374742108, -0.0361458397090175, 0.199806590200299, 
-0.0923939579395243, 0.300258558209524, 0.307083208123854, -0.372662607142777, 
-0.0572583319729891, 0.644732889957074, -0.0904118240718854, 
-0.143029858612403, -0.187615998952944, 0.121964949216529, 0.0531386426015056, 
0.0624749217328398, 0.206863803305199, -0.262259708980188, 0.0726333418651898, 
-0.103658323178436, -0.296071442543119, 0.226374016486998, -0.13440366483565, 
0.105501678602159, -0.130030639213654, -0.0110364477837153, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.26968371426098, -0.0155890673729734, -0.184284451840467, 
-0.0633697628527222, -0.0756406653509469, 0.227411948775754, 
NA, NA, -0.125345469385346, -0.0224828981838005, 0.161597493963613, 
0.0371197944548526, 0.0148541820967762, -0.189921774311887, -0.397832457796958, 
-0.0582032827727681, -0.0764673867131659, -0.0497957441923001, 
NA, NA, 0.0449605522472631, 0.0140435671785606, 0.115644287199413, 
-0.163612728982696, -0.0369305763029631, 0.152739947872823, -0.181575371181168, 
0.154621954754853, NA, NA, -0.314553803719056, 0.344799633261712, 
0.0192799528247013, -0.098685769455291, -0.124360554540428, 0.157860234941791, 
-0.260396218951657, 0.239485632172963, -0.208741410333448, 0.250827260972775, 
-0.142971536264546, 0.207405918032745, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0439580344807332, 
-0.00181528986796664, -0.0139516499838043, -0.0328095707998725, 
-0.0789083514987792, 0.0858281285285902, 0.196262693708447, -0.36649818106507, 
0.190538516279416, -0.24916090647245, -0.0728720117481969, -0.0191284575760859, 
-0.243389660492848, 0.235641344386585, -0.139766107251914, 0.062247028731737, 
-0.246899059846911, 0.178223227792211, -0.190726027555047, -0.0407223282975083, 
-0.108655590226593, 0.141082171706391, -0.183351948608341, 0.236140466617194, 
0.0336232516784701, 0.159891906857505, -0.244268390987204, 0.229391964824989, 
-0.14224137016854, -0.0370043853074932, 0.198093698676019, -0.0745427825448673, 
-0.18751615569672, 0.0252952801902908, 0.0148541820967762, -0.189921774311887, 
-0.141718980419485, 0.06303858589334, -0.0798637131409112, 0.0206753397045604, 
0.0658995925160964, -0.182462081862579, -0.293310524503675, -0.103785090955044, 
-0.205789421986016, 0.0737216228863557, -0.18743150613592, 0.0244709344941872, 
0.0523090211391174, -0.327774911814208, -0.383791289381148, 0.0224717952896955, 
-0.0489466663793394, 0.100849338204541, -0.205632282008697, 0.112731143201648, 
NA, NA, -0.0791422176742333, -0.183122879592945, -0.256251541372125, 
0.32075114702689, -0.109056115482951, -0.437581856952708, 0.168565776593927, 
0.0112315186467975, 0.0205230712251415, -0.152633262615199, NA, 
NA, -0.00559346627671493, -0.105939600710423, -0.243200334585682, 
-0.0229886745335356, -0.313000186357086, -0.108806585468647, 
0.0629844853565044, -0.124978427715945, -0.0998156929088808, 
0.28918613444771, -0.229029771129634, 0.17860401699821, 0.192976395550239, 
0.0674795315940469, 0.22208076381171, -0.0653077742729489, -0.00441092879437654, 
-0.152151871343017, -0.0542585474086585, -0.182156022157871, 
0.0243360827586908, -0.159456853362232, -0.315451438915062, 0.00479586764109896, 
-0.0658226744519441, -0.054022622684617, -0.14684354898579, -0.0896047917744014, 
0.195921804059387, -0.226971922068303, -0.254313406940928, 0.0745354964465048, 
0.128381070000955, -0.157056282544603, -0.138751496766607, -0.0562634415442843, 
-0.121197670553226, -0.086160697551453, -0.00237992724559371, 
-0.115638431740053, NA, NA, -0.0443131642566608, -0.062570457797265, 
0.0523959206070392, -0.26451277545694, 0.324554215403563, -0.354636832149615, 
0.0900046149894463, -0.21360124829462, 0.328849018719503, -0.563194911556135, 
0.0385188334418423, -0.208681554453189, NA, NA, -0.116449694964364, 
0.173898476234437, -0.0122353221226405, -0.242859992554905, 0.210779556914438, 
-0.136979289161418, 0.112849182471408, -0.0110878937045105, 0.131675159121585, 
0.0322369268631404, 0.0722503560841253, -0.105559617713625, 0.145702587734005, 
-0.114055843186341, 0.00897168069912057, -0.152779535607564, 
0.185416115132091, 0.139648936171848, -0.339435712322975, 0.188493277626503, 
-0.219576557100002, 0.0467816679929099, -0.131853773373089, 0.355835047322506, 
-0.116170318459756, -0.0062172053864046, -0.00175143214065898, 
-0.20938447143972, NA, NA, -0.0645228798411095, -0.053029560023961, 
NA, NA, -0.0579625705349727, -0.0879095942957547, -0.0455126985613822, 
0.137286630347203, 0.0544159282310674, -0.111029350609663, -0.305157448976381, 
0.00287650667329221, -0.0963772261791161, 0.0141550428169644, 
-0.118323505439401, 0.0263086012994963, NA, NA, 0.0946996437488379, 
-0.0281882901839543, -0.264830491470819, -0.00560255714547876, 
NA, NA, 0.0287172038730819, -0.12287491123785, 0.170618969726522, 
-0.326371890456747, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0074222793941661, -0.178073160886772, 
-0.0375507862866806, -0.182780598851118, 0.174405365634955, -0.0244120019683591, 
-0.122779951693592, -0.115042812668123, -0.137871428426028, -0.211317089796517, 
-0.258126039429376, -0.193566134112804, 0.00147105642397745, 
-0.106264366711376, -0.14006867589864, 0.182331899630885, -0.0218154837408014, 
0.356667547454766, -0.0412310716225777, 0.00258551517278575, 
-0.0339760949801102, -0.0573451484471943, -0.179844910648036, 
0.0601934923986177, -0.0954311733961448, -0.257716546080691, 
-0.164487954057847, 0.224289601070542, -0.00450016672450693, 
0.161798490365034, -0.111255908346463, 0.00906404808218765, 0.00707737733818487, 
-0.225878282983652, NA, NA, -0.205008285258871, 0.0543934055830302, 
0.012953293999785, -0.199688812112181, -0.105178786172577, 0.0560530628822707, 
0.00672275694888985, -0.231344038330046, -0.0807995561538029, 
0.0412518012555594, -0.0386808218946201, -0.113881835400778, 
0.111253966201852, -0.266822480171457, 0.0600113076474125, 0.126601954785962, 
0.185063704213823, 0.166017397633998, NA, NA, 0.0105619900125018, 
-0.18651120773984, 0.0763268563546143, -0.166665309941193, -0.178580845628754, 
-0.233312517579627, -0.0481684063571434, -0.077797048088731, 
-0.203280994156471, -0.142581544437585, 0.0255836118745615, -0.0276336831868125, 
-0.0295129513017942, 0.0674858668793503, 0.135260909059116, -0.0927405173056505, 
0.0744990456655177, -0.144738862753733, -0.237192573939147, 0.160141253589785, 
0.142147193792261, -0.187992976443227, -0.216446688136037, -0.16105196661471, 
-0.0508237785151704, 0.118627591076543, -0.182898710862875, 0.0707376228068899, 
-0.193890924258218, 0.0900954283356207, 0.00401622925185781, 
-0.195921324986153, -0.0694101254841401, 0.0775580321503677, 
0.108041719522084, 0.0396115053067626, -0.0458284022403393, -0.218871555395771, 
0.121440522444865, -0.0572042815635894, -0.22218652218659, 0.0248185058615541, 
0.20938839175807, 0.132481057338594, -0.180258610941658, -0.0284142478612041, 
-0.21671672952526, 0.194763389382272, 0.0364715948504319, -0.0657975195408112, 
-0.0563040880456959, -0.109544685418116, NA, NA, 0.0648057072675422, 
-0.157786229573645, -0.00638799728608172, -0.128516028136478, 
0.154035375347516, -0.339760203241564, NA, NA, -0.0864268879423147, 
0.0131312434942388, NA, NA, -0.205461907805209, -0.130332837170351, 
-0.206680676605858, 0.136703988067015, -0.174060373675473, 0.0659448601839198, 
-0.0580533126015975, -0.0314593831638318, -0.0920101781411946, 
0.25675637702712, -0.27470347980719, 0.295884532407143, 0.151243691290212, 
0.348292828320822, -0.0164280622109516, 0.0294134305588641, -0.355313617294638, 
-0.0496116046792636, NA, NA, 0.208051615507144, 0.0612230994890477, 
-0.296772891159623, 0.106373198893925, -0.0564000131604138, -0.13755092784139, 
-0.0946301230487614, -0.217984541666007, -0.0113011118872734, 
-0.353759404722727, NA, NA, -0.125290458742648, 0.0582470395976115, 
-0.114798167159317, 0.101545514768859, 0.081099183231184, -0.0827437844416916, 
-0.103933326795975, 0.0368614189812161, -0.261860493414426, -0.0839879795872783, 
-0.138957366652903, -0.137790816073706, -0.153452701090709, -0.445014708107295, 
0.0096604780196279, 0.134783916221383, 0.0452900996550472, -0.210708736380164, 
0.0621242385590066, -0.0514563799465529, -0.00744713312770768, 
0.0250887647061372, -0.116959036351569, -0.085224863529069, -0.38853419499807, 
-0.189952634118266, -0.218665695216765, 0.467745176730558, -0.336315754204112, 
0.249063676234904, -0.104035042076053, -0.136859566609601, 0.0525495025377563, 
-0.454589141329014, -0.0519257847232248, 0.0205225076770941, 
-0.178737694570114, -0.155275617904206, -0.00237992724559371, 
-0.115638431740053, -0.110518678178894, -0.108372682262173, -0.287709060609944, 
0.0371322942937481, 0.066671589858597, -0.391606873099472, 0.126226324658725, 
-0.399388231127899, -0.203849571318033, -0.100361249758939, NA, 
NA, -0.187166335014545, -0.124685973058729, -0.191261034341373, 
0.125557120478446, NA, NA, -0.172192663023502, 0.0210935670934318, 
0.0437454640495771, 0.0649474707755941, -0.0307560655211706, 
-0.155943348564083, -0.100459894129437, -0.0837349103788484, 
NA, NA, -0.0467230775481449, 0.0445367556198534, -0.0258221029555385, 
-0.337769379137755, -0.0949717047071838, -0.0653334039042102, 
-0.0916244514588163, 0.208385897193025, -0.0139516499838043, 
-0.0328095707998725, 0.108756365899433, -0.205946694745602, 0.0444850847582909, 
-0.0456047105712402, -0.123080606885036, 0.166004972978278, -0.0540745862900131, 
-0.104383649403864, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.256514651048856, 0.0389502818708297, 
-0.155885002949447, -0.145172040814028, -0.0197648643935328, 
-0.154228761470774, -0.245465986869158, 0.196050394893124, -0.0629062361879831, 
-0.0418851053863066, -0.0883849505943926, 0.167116542912757, 
NA, NA, -0.0945325286387913, -0.244297051453914, 0.0994391613316947, 
-0.0414589626231581, -0.0021774093388973, 0.0789953240584772, 
-0.28851469166179, 0.212678450880014, 0.178853309299823, 0.0160852171949784, 
NA, NA, -0.0724021587657935, -0.0726525233071279, 0.0641256540271004, 
-0.247109926514703, 0.261007190593326, 0.162365145316339, 0.183695385237096, 
-0.160854132104893, 0.0254757957933874, 0.159302424608104, 0.0536504218846581, 
0.0947326442990328, -0.0739825582591165, -0.023444526981956, 
NA, NA, -0.246445416033503, 0.0421799991254654, 0.171399843165558, 
0.121857838781291, 0.131291806491966, -0.0310256969763662, 0.084932656034447, 
0.319694044603215, -0.0889318830147494, 0.244658060764321, -0.0962644796304246, 
-0.0406925583175, 0.0719899653174018, 0.186970645556985, -0.269454328187128, 
0.115075337197967, NA, NA, 0.124683035292236, 0.0203697993225934, 
-0.188138124518597, 0.0454961850788923, -0.0506301523232337, 
0.283829223238744, NA, NA, 0.012953293999785, -0.199688812112181, 
-0.0414576280113129, 0.195648813114567, -0.178532798762864, 0.0495794181231349, 
-0.284278159207787, 0.119933984376387, -0.0736119199628618, -0.0519048539144688, 
-0.193631407386575, -0.289684365032212, 0.0521560438562125, -0.122037909970877, 
-0.136878270640725, 0.149803202303949, 0.0153790015443654, 0.0202694351487697, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0756117605914394, 0.148175208233554, 
-0.271295578246216, 0.409493126095501, -0.01568142586576, -0.0648911279001933, 
NA, NA, 0.0671711556674623, 0.0618219987103883, 0.133024970982326, 
-0.193030566840229, -0.0158360602199258, -0.0866160392870411, 
-0.0675782565096752, -0.0751017710958831, -0.220393224448939, 
-0.00966063181064768, -0.0996194859966963, -0.0991640377156096, 
0.0726333418651898, -0.103658323178436, -0.27364637703548, 0.273019847922917, 
-0.0781696117636672, 0.129417247633593, 0.0297980677565262, -0.134352011645225, 
-0.118604292468149, -0.190775713471729, -0.16647638154017, -0.0762085246815682, 
-0.0891311686769857, -0.163661512890215, 0.31722215300791, -0.275034100117617, 
-0.129169755185721, -0.00241222587250762, -0.107647650941447, 
0.127604415704785, -0.166092508902277, -0.195686403184036, 0.0318623953980768, 
0.141089701919201, NA, NA, -0.0961135302259641, -0.0798572664410973, 
NA, NA, -0.0461883921074545, 0.0834756138899552, -0.08487553609808, 
0.00963537949551373, -0.165936066953134, 0.0111744666718458, 
-0.0908197261353577, -0.156010494847943, -0.260674035822964, 
-0.114751621595064, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0136054096164949, -0.0185447185244471, 
-0.122981079778463, -0.0111990675185473, -0.182298509501045, 
-0.388317916380626, -0.153758412306888, 0.261778719392714, -0.217254978152196, 
0.191612183539808, NA, NA, -0.136777432491356, -0.114496580430642, 
-0.02969812077836, -0.268652077750056, -0.0508640036811775, -0.000711744011523578, 
0.317425038435027, 0.134985042790569, NA, NA), .Dim = c(2L, 500L
), .Dimnames = list(c("tumor_Mes", "tumor_Epi"), c("5_8S_rRNA", 
"5S_rRNA", "7SK", "A1BG", "A1BG-AS1", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2M-AS1", 
"A2ML1", "A2ML1-AS1", "A2ML1-AS2", "A2MP1", "A3GALT2", "A4GALT", 
"A4GNT", "AA06", "AAAS", "AACS", "AACSP1", "AADAC", "AADACL2", 
"AADACL2-AS1", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", "AADACP1", "AADAT", "AAED1", 
"AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMDC", "AAMP", "AANAT", "AAR2", "AARD", "AARS", 
"AARS2", "AARSD1", "AARSP1", "AASDH", "AASDHPPT", "AASS", "AATBC", 
"AATF", "AATK", "AATK-AS1", "AB015752.3", "AB019438.66", "AB019440.50", 
"AB019441.29", "ABALON", "ABAT", "ABBA01017803.1", "ABC12-47043100G14.2", 
"ABC12-47964100C23.1", "ABC12-49244600F4.4", "ABC14-1080714F14.1", 
"ABC7-42391500H16.2", "ABC7-42418200C9.1", "ABC7-43041300I9.1", 
"ABC7-481722F1.1", "ABCA1", "ABCA10", "ABCA11P", "ABCA12", "ABCA13", 
"ABCA17P", "ABCA2", "ABCA3", "ABCA4", "ABCA5", "ABCA6", "ABCA7", 
"ABCA8", "ABCA9", "ABCA9-AS1", "ABCB1", "ABCB10", "ABCB10P1", 
"ABCB10P3", "ABCB10P4", "ABCB11", "ABCB4", "ABCB5", "ABCB6", 
"ABCB7", "ABCB8", "ABCB9", "ABCC1", "ABCC10", "ABCC11", "ABCC12", 
"ABCC13", "ABCC2", "ABCC3", "ABCC4", "ABCC5", "ABCC5-AS1", "ABCC6", 
"ABCC6P1", "ABCC6P2", "ABCC8", "ABCC9", "ABCD1", "ABCD1P2", "ABCD1P3", 
"ABCD1P4", "ABCD1P5", "ABCD2", "ABCD3", "ABCD4", "ABCE1", "ABCF1", 
"ABCF2", "ABCF2P1", "ABCF2P2", "ABCF3", "ABCG1", "ABCG2", "ABCG4", 
"ABCG5", "ABCG8", "ABHD1", "ABHD10", "ABHD11", "ABHD11-AS1", 
"ABHD12", "ABHD12B", "ABHD13", "ABHD14A", "ABHD14A-ACY1", "ABHD14B", 
"ABHD15", "ABHD15-AS1", "ABHD16A", "ABHD16B", "ABHD17A", "ABHD17AP1", 
"ABHD17AP3", "ABHD17AP4", "ABHD17AP6", "ABHD17AP9", "ABHD17B", 
"ABHD17C", "ABHD2", "ABHD3", "ABHD4", "ABHD5", "ABHD6", "ABHD8", 
"ABI1", "ABI2", "ABI3", "ABI3BP", "ABL1", "ABL2", "ABLIM1", "ABLIM2", 
"ABLIM3", "ABO", "ABR", "ABRA", "ABRACL", "ABT1", "ABT1P1", "ABTB1", 
"ABTB2", "AC000003.1", "AC000029.1", "AC000032.2", "AC000036.4", 
"AC000041.10", "AC000041.8", "AC000067.1", "AC000068.10", "AC000068.5", 
"AC000068.9", "AC000077.2", "AC000078.5", "AC000081.2", "AC000089.3", 
"AC000095.11", "AC000095.9", "AC000099.1", "AC000110.1", "AC000111.3", 
"AC000111.4", "AC000111.5", "AC000111.6", "AC000120.7", "AC000123.2", 
"AC000123.3", "AC000123.4", "AC000124.1", "AC000354.1", "AC000362.1", 
"AC000367.1", "AC000370.2", "AC000374.1", "AC000403.1", "AC000403.4", 
"AC001226.7", "AC002044.1", "AC002044.3", "AC002044.4", "AC002056.3", 
"AC002056.5", "AC002059.10", "AC002064.4", "AC002064.5", "AC002064.7", 
"AC002066.1", "AC002069.5", "AC002069.6", "AC002070.1", "AC002072.1", 
"AC002075.3", "AC002075.4", "AC002076.10", "AC002115.5", "AC002115.9", 
"AC002116.7", "AC002116.8", "AC002117.1", "AC002127.2", "AC002127.4", 
"AC002128.5", "AC002306.1", "AC002310.10", "AC002310.12", "AC002310.13", 
"AC002310.14", "AC002310.17", "AC002310.7", "AC002314.4", "AC002331.1", 
"AC002365.5", "AC002366.1", "AC002366.3", "AC002368.4", "AC002383.2", 
"AC002386.1", "AC002389.1", "AC002395.1", "AC002398.11", "AC002398.12", 
"AC002398.13", "AC002398.9", "AC002400.1", "AC002401.1", "AC002407.1", 
"AC002429.1", "AC002429.4", "AC002429.5", "AC002451.3", "AC002454.1", 
"AC002456.2", "AC002463.3", "AC002464.1", "AC002465.2", "AC002467.7", 
"AC002472.11", "AC002480.2", "AC002480.3", "AC002480.4", "AC002480.5", 
"AC002486.2", "AC002486.3", "AC002511.2", "AC002511.3", "AC002519.6", 
"AC002519.8", "AC002523.1", "AC002530.1", "AC002539.1", "AC002539.2", 
"AC002542.2", "AC002543.2", "AC002550.5", "AC002550.6", "AC002551.1", 
"AC002553.4", "AC002558.1", "AC002978.1", "AC002979.1", "AC002981.1", 
"AC002984.2", "AC002985.3", "AC003001.1", "AC003002.4", "AC003002.6", 
"AC003003.5", "AC003005.2", "AC003005.4", "AC003006.1", "AC003006.7", 
"AC003009.1", "AC003045.1", "AC003075.4", "AC003080.4", "AC003084.2", 
"AC003088.1", "AC003090.1", "AC003092.1", "AC003092.2", "AC003101.1", 
"AC003104.1", "AC003658.1", "AC003664.1", "AC003666.1", "AC003681.1", 
"AC003682.16", "AC003682.17", "AC003688.1", "AC003956.1", "AC003958.2", 
"AC003958.6", "AC003968.1", "AC003973.1", "AC003973.3", "AC003973.4", 
"AC003973.5", "AC003984.1", "AC003985.1", "AC003986.5", "AC003986.6", 
"AC003986.7", "AC003988.1", "AC003989.3", "AC003989.4", "AC003991.3", 
"AC004000.1", "AC004000.2", "AC004004.2", "AC004006.2", "AC004009.1", 
"AC004009.2", "AC004009.3", "AC004012.1", "AC004014.3", "AC004014.4", 
"AC004016.1", "AC004019.10", "AC004019.13", "AC004022.7", "AC004022.8", 
"AC004041.2", "AC004051.2", "AC004052.1", "AC004053.1", "AC004053.2", 
"AC004054.1", "AC004057.1", "AC004062.2", "AC004063.1", "AC004066.2", 
"AC004066.3", "AC004067.5", "AC004069.1", "AC004069.2", "AC004070.1", 
"AC004074.4", "AC004076.5", "AC004076.7", "AC004076.9", "AC004079.1", 
"AC004108.1", "AC004112.4", "AC004112.5", "AC004112.7", "AC004125.3", 
"AC004129.7", "AC004129.9", "AC004156.3", "AC004158.1", "AC004158.3", 
"AC004159.1", "AC004160.4", "AC004166.6", "AC004221.2", "AC004231.2", 
"AC004237.1", "AC004257.1", "AC004381.6", "AC004381.7", "AC004383.3", 
"AC004386.3", "AC004386.4", "AC004447.2", "AC004448.2", "AC004448.5", 
"AC004449.6", "AC004453.1", "AC004453.8", "AC004458.1", "AC004460.1", 
"AC004461.4", "AC004470.1", "AC004471.10", "AC004471.9", "AC004477.1", 
"AC004485.3", "AC004490.1", "AC004492.1", "AC004510.3", "AC004520.1", 
"AC004535.2", "AC004538.3", "AC004540.4", "AC004540.5", "AC004541.1", 
"AC004543.1", "AC004543.2", "AC004549.6", "AC004552.1", "AC004593.3", 
"AC004595.1", "AC004603.4", "AC004623.2", "AC004623.3", "AC004637.1", 
"AC004655.1", "AC004656.1", "AC004673.1", "AC004687.1", "AC004691.1", 
"AC004691.5", "AC004692.4", "AC004692.5", "AC004699.1", "AC004702.2", 
"AC004744.3", "AC004745.1", "AC004754.3", "AC004769.1", "AC004775.5", 
"AC004791.2", "AC004812.1", "AC004813.1", "AC004816.1", "AC004819.1", 
"AC004824.1", "AC004824.2", "AC004832.1", "AC004837.1", "AC004837.3", 
"AC004837.4", "AC004837.5", "AC004840.8", "AC004846.1", "AC004850.1", 
"AC004854.4", "AC004854.5", "AC004862.6", "AC004866.1", "AC004866.3", 
"AC004869.2", "AC004869.3", "AC004870.3", "AC004870.4", "AC004870.5", 
"AC004875.1", "AC004878.2", "AC004878.8", "AC004893.10", "AC004893.11", 
"AC004895.1", "AC004895.4", "AC004899.3", "AC004901.1", "AC004906.3", 
"AC004911.2", "AC004915.1", "AC004920.2", "AC004920.3", "AC004924.1", 
"AC004932.1", "AC004938.5", "AC004941.3", "AC004941.5", "AC004943.1", 
"AC004945.1", "AC004946.1", "AC004947.2", "AC004951.5", "AC004951.6", 
"AC004953.1", "AC004967.7", "AC004969.1", "AC004980.1", "AC004980.10", 
"AC004980.11", "AC004980.7", "AC004980.8", "AC004980.9", "AC004984.1", 
"AC004985.12", "AC004987.10", "AC004987.9", "AC004988.1", "AC005000.1"
)))
```

This gives me

cormat_UCS_pearson as

```
structure(c(1, NA, NA, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("tumor_Mes", "tumor_Epi"), c("tumor_Mes", "tumor_Epi")))
```

Since the values are either 1 or NAs, I cannot move ahead to plot a graph for the same.

Any suggestion to help circumvent this shall be helpful.

Comment: How about this? `cormat_UCS_pearson <- round(cor(na.omit(t(UCS_pearson))),5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial steps of my codes produced certain NAs and I had to rectify them in order to get the correct plot.